# How to post JSON form data into classic asp form handler

Tags: json, forms, asp-classic, handler

i had an html form posting data to a classic asp script and writing the data into a database. it was working well.  I switched to a form creation utility called unbounce which sends form data in json. Now my data isn't going through.

Data generated  by my form looks like this http://www.postbin.org/1drboi4

What steps must I take to my classic asp to accept the json data from my unbounce forms?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your application that receives the data from the form post so that now, instead of receiving form data it receives the JSON data, parses it, and then does with it what ever it is that it currently does with the data.

In other words, you need to completely change the logic from one method of data handling to another.  I hear this is a good frameowrk for using JSON data with ASP.

http://framework.lojcomm.com.br/app/docs/files/app/core/lib/json-class-asp.html